# Etiquette of GitHub Contributing, Pull Requests vs New Issue

Tags: open-source, github, pull-request

I was wondering what the proper etiquette to contributing on GitHub is?

Should you submit a *"New Issue"* first and discuss the problem?

Or do you take some initiative, code, then do a *"Pull Request"* and discuss the code further there?

My concern with creating a *"New Issue"* first is that if you do a *"Pull Request"* after, there would be two issues #'s created... seems like a waste.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is quite clear:

- if you don't think you can contribute back a patch, open a new *issue* ([following the same kind of checklist than the one described here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue)).
- if you think you can make some patch to fix the issue, fork the repo, and make a [*pull request*](https://help.github.com/categories/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/) (once you have pushed your patch back to your fork).

If you make a pull issue first, and then create a pull request, nothing stops you to reference the issue URL in your pull request comment, in order to avoid writing *again* the context of your patch.

Comment: Before doing all this ask on the mailing list first (if any)!!